# Updating an Android SQLite Database on Field Change

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, auto-update

I'm writing an android application and on one of my pages, I have a text field, a spinner, and a date picker that need to be saved/updated in a SQLite database. All three have default values on creation, and the database needs to update any time a field is changed (there's no 'Save' button or anything like that). I've looked into using an onFocusChangeListener() for this, but it seems like the application only changes focus when using text fields, so it wouldn't work with a spinner or datepicker. I've also tried splitting the components into fragments and overwriting the onPause() method with update functionalities thinking that the fragments paused when the user moved on to the next one but I think that it still only checks when the user leaves the screen. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Spinner` you can try [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29), for `Datepicker`, try [OnDateChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html)